# Python-DjangoREST-uWSGi-nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

This is my first time posting and its a pretty long question.
I'm a beginner and I've decided to learn and use Python and DjangoREST to build my first web application.

Unfortunately, I have a lot of issues that I'm not sure how to get answers to. Querying Google one at a time for each component is giving me answers that sometimes conflicts with another component.

First things first, the following is my project setup:-

- OS->Ubuntu 16.04.1
- Backend->Python3 and DjangoREST
- Webserver->uWSGI and nginx
- Database->PostgreSQL
- Client Side software->AngularJS(which requires the setup of Node.js and NPM)

Now I installed pip and went through the process of creating a virtualenv and ran a test Django app. I was able to get that done.

When I went through the documentation of uWSGI and Nginx over here http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html, I came across the following line

**the web client <-> the web server <-> the socket <-> uwsgi <-> Django**

This has me slightly confused. Is there a specific order in which I need to install the software I need? And if yes, could you all tell me the correct order?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It only tells you the order in which the interactions occur when a web page is visited; not the order you should install the software.

Comment: You have mentioned you are creating a web app.Are you trying to create API for your web application??Because if you are not you should be using Django framework.DRF is not required.

Comment: Yes I will be creating Rest APIs using DRF.

Comment: There is no order for installation.This gives you information about how the interaction takes place between all the different components.Just make sure you have installed all of the above and you are good to go!!

Comment: Understood. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually the order you should install software. This is the communication flow in which you(your browser) connect to the django application on your server.

To make work your application in your server you should do the followings:

1. First install nginx (reverse proxy server and a web server as well)
2. Install Gunicorn (wsgi server implementation)
3. Clone your django project in any directory from your remote git (or simply upload it from local pc)
4. now run the below command inside the project directory

```
gunicorn YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.wsgi:application \
  --name GIVE_A_NAME_AS_YOUR_WISH \
  --worker-connections=1000 \
  --threads=3 \
  --workers NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=USER --group=GROUP \
  --bind=SERVER_HOST:ANY_PORT_AS_YOUR_CHOICE (TYPICALLY IT IS 8000)
```

5. Point number 4 is enough to run your project in your server. check it in the below link
   http://YOUR_HOST_ADDRESS:8000/

Now you can redirect all of your traffic to this application by nginx web server configuration. To do so make a file inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` naming `my_app.conf`. inside this file copy paste the below code:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;        
    }
}
```

Hopefully it is okay !